# Why did my micro-controller short out even though the alligator clip of the oscilloscope was connected to a ground pin?

Tags: embedded, stm32

I have a STM32F407G-Discovery board, and I bought a DS1054Z oscilloscope for the purposes of debugging.

Before I did anything, I went through videos and articles about how to use it. From my very basic understanding of them, I gathered that since my MCU was connected to my computer through a USB, it was a mains earth reference, and so I need to be careful about where I plug the alligator clip of the oscilloscope.

As such, I made sure to connect the alligator clip to a pin titled GND. However, as soon as I did, the LEDs on the MCU faded away and they just stopped working. I can no longer flash any code onto my MCU.

Here's a picture of the board:
[image]

This is where I connected the alligator clip: the far right side of the board. The GND pin above the 5V pin which is above the 3V pin which is above the PH1 pin.

My plan was to connect the alligator clip to this GND pin, and then use the longer probe (not sure what's it called) to hook onto the PE3 pin (since I'm trying to debug a SPI issue). Was my logic incorrect?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The "longer probe" is just called "the probe" - the ground is the ground (_not_ a probe).  I would not have connected a croc-clip to a GND adjacent to a power rail for starters - it only has to swing around to short the supply.  Clip it to the top of the crystal or the USB connector casing in future.  You live and learn.  In the schematic, 5V is supplied from the USB 5V via D1 - you may have simply burned D1 - use an external 5V bench supply (which bypasses D1) and see if it starts up.

Comment: Tempted to write an answer "you must isolate your crocodiles so that they stay on the ground".  (A good crocodile clip on the scope probe will have plastic all the way out to the tip.)

Comment: I use kapton tape to isolate my crocodiles

Comment: @Clifford thanks for the info. Also - when you say clip to the USB connector, are you referring to the gold colored part at the top? So is that and the crystal guaranteed to safe to clip the ground onto?
Others have suggested kapton tape (@laptop2d) as well as just paper (@pipe). Want to be sure before I try it on my other board.

Comment: In most designs the metal outer of any connector will be grounded - use a multimeter/continuity tester to verify if in doubt, but in this case it is clearly shown in the schematic for CN5 and CN1 - I am less certain about X2 - don't trust me on that!  The "gold colour" looks like Kapton tape, so will be an insulator - you may need to remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This is a dangerous-looking setup.  Connecting the ground clip of the scope probe to one of the GND pins was correct electrically, but a bad idea because stuff happens.

I think it's 80% likely that the ground clip swiveled around and touched the 5 V pin when you didn't notice.  This can happen very easily.  I wouldn't use a alligator clip on a pin like that for exactly this reason.  It is OK to use a "hook" clip, but be careful about them coming loose and popping off the pin and then hitting something else.

A possible option for your case is to clip to both GND pins together.  The alligator clip would come from the top of the picture, and only reach far enough to touch the two GND pins.  I still don't like that since it *will* pop off eventually, and then you've got a ground connection flailing around randomly shorting things.

What I use for these cases is a short wire that has a female pin meant for a RS-232 connector on one end and about ¼ inch of bare wire on the other.  The whole thing is about 1½ inches long.  The female connector has heat shrink tubing around it so that it is insulated on the outside.  Slide the female connector over the pin, then clip the scope probe ground to the short end of bare wire.

Comment: A simple temporary option that works in a "corner case" like this is to fold a small piece of paper and put between the ground clip and the pins you _don't_ want to accidentally short out.

Comment: Ended up going with your idea of using a short wire with the female pin. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

If you have shorted the 5V pin to GND as @Hein suspects, it would overload and burn out the D1 diode to the right of the USB socket, if the overload protection of the host port does not shut it down fast enough. See the schematics in the [board manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf)

[image]

`U5V` comes from the USB wire, `5V` goes directly to the pin.

You can do a quick test:

- connect the board to a powered hub or an USB charger
- connect the pins of the diode together, e.g. with a pair of tweezers

If the board comes back to life, then you can try replacing the diode with a similar one. You can even short it permanently, but then you should be really careful with what you are connecting to the board, as this diode would protect the host USB port from overvoltage.

I did the same with a discovery board once. The diode actually went up in a puff of smoke, as it was connected through a cheap USB hub that apparently lacked proper overcurrent protection.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've never replaced a diode or done anything with electronics before, so I'll need to research thoroughly before getting started. I'll look into it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

You understood it correctly it seems. The ground of the oscilloscope is connected to the ground of your DISCO through the mains, you were correct in using precaution.

But, is it possible that you crocodile clip accidentally swirled around the ground pin, and so touched 5V pin? This would have burned out something, but it should not have damaged the MCU. This is also something that you have to look out for.

**My guesses:**

- You burnt out your USB port. A typical USB port can only handle 500mA, and such a short can definitely damage it. Try another USB port.
- You damaged your board. On the datasheet it seems those pins can only handle 100mA, which gives this a higher chance of breaking. This is harder to fix, as I struggle to find enough information on the datasheet. If you have another DISCO board, then you could that one's programmer (ST-LinkV2) to try and program your broken board's MCU. If that works, it means your ST-LinkV2 burnt out.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:** Seems @berendi has better eyes than I do. He suggests that diode `D1` might have burnt out, which seems like the obvious problem. Please see his answer for further details on how debug/fix it.

Comment: At university we studied on these discovery boards. Half the class had to replace that exact diode

Comment: I've had first-hand experience :)